# Update 2 rows from three based on duplicated value

Tags: sql, t-sql

How can I update all duplicated `site_id` rows except the last one. I.e. if I have 3 duplicated site ids (2 in this case), how can I update the top two leaving the last (third) one untouched?

```
temp_id site_id amount
1            2  200
2            2  200
3            2  200
4            3  200
5            3  200
6            4  200
```

CREATE TABLE #site (temp_id NUMERIC IDENTITY,
                          site_id NUMERIC PRIMARY KEY 
                          )

```
INSERT INTO #site VALUES(2),(3),(4)

CREATE TABLE #temp (temp_id NUMERIC IDENTITY,
                      site_id NUMERIC FOREIGN KEY (site_id)       REFERENCES #site(site_id), 
                      amount  NUMERIC)

 INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(2,200),(2,200),(2,200),(3,200),(3,200),(4,200)

update #temp
set amount = 2
where site_id in (
select distinct table1.site_id
from #temp table1
inner join #temp table2 on table1.site_id = table2.site_id
and table1.temp_id <> table2.temp_id
)
and site_id <> (
select max(site_id)
from #temp
);


SELECT t.* FROM #temp t
JOIN #site            s ON s.site_id = t.site_id


DROP TABLE #temp
DROP TABLE #site
```

Comment: What's the name of the table?

Comment: #temp_record with site_id as foreign key on temp_site

Comment: Is `temp_id` a unique key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE temp_record
    SET …
    WHERE site_id = 2
        AND temp_id <> (SELECT MAX(temp_id)
                            FROM my_table
                            WHERE site_id = 2)
```

If you want to update all such lines and `temp_id` is a unique key in `temp_record`:

```
UPDATE temp_record
    SET …
    WHERE temp_id NOT IN (
        SELECT MAX(temp_id)
            FROM temp_record
            GROUP BY site_id)
```

Comment: Need to update all duplicated records leaving the last one. In this case the site id 3 will not get updated.

Answer (score 2):

My preferred way of doing this is with `row_number()`:

```
with toupdate as (
     select t.*,
            row_number() over (partition by site_id order by temp_id desc) as seqnum
     from t
)
update t
    set . . .
    where seqnum = 1
```

I'm not filling in the details.  Just giving you an alternative approach.